# Use both ARC and non-ARC versions from the same project get duplicated symbol error

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This question is somehow similar to the ones about how to make ARC and non-ARC code work together, but this is a bit different because both the ARC and non-ARC code I need to use is actually from the same project. Detailed information below:

I have been using the ARC enabled [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) in my project for a while and everything was fine util [sinaweibosdkforoauth2](http://code.google.com/p/sinaweibosdkforoauth2/) needs to be included. By following [Mixing ARC and Non-ARC Code with Static Libraries](http://www.seriousmonster.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/) I was able to use a non-ARC project in an ARC enabled project, the real problem for me was that sinaweibosdkforoauth2 requests a non-ARC enabled SBJson(at that time it was json-framework on google code) so during linking time I got an error saying that duplicate symbol(e.g. SBJsonWriter) was found.

One possible solution to this I've found on internet was to rename the duplicate class name in either project. I haven't tried this yet because I don't wanna touch the 3rd-party source code. Is it possible? Or am I going the complete wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting confused. Nothing can "require" a non-ARC enabled SBJSON. ARC code is wholly compatible with non-ARC code. Just include SBJSON once in your project, and it doesn't matter if it's ARC or not.

Comment: Well the problem is that the source code of the non-ARC SBJSON is a bit different than the ARC version(e.g. class names). So in order to use ARC enabled SBJSON everywhere I still need to touch the 3rd-party library, [sinaweibosdkforoauth2](http://code.google.com/p/sinaweibosdkforoauth2/) in this case. Eventually I just added prefix _Legacy_ to all classes in the non-ARC enabled SBJSON and until now it seems all working.

Comment: Why is the source different? Did they modify their own copy of SBJSON? That's a pretty odd thing to do.

Comment: I guess an old non-ARC version is used. For example, for the non-ARC version there is a class called SBJsonBase but there is no such class in the ARC enabled version. Even though I think maybe it's still possible to just use the ARC version because in my APP I probably will not use SBJsonBase directly. Anyway since now everything works I won't try it now, but thanks for the idea so maybe in the future I can try the way you suggested.